Higher Dimensional Spherical Harmonics in Cartesian Form
Are there any tables in the literature or computer software for computing higher dimensional spherical harmonics in Cartesian form, like this Wikipedia article, which lists them for three dimensions.
Obviously, one could take the general form in hyper-spherical coordinates that use Legendre polynomials and invert the spherical coordinate transformation. But this seems quite slow for computer algebra software. Is there a quicker way?
I am particularly interested in spherical harmonics in four dimensions.

I think this follows from the definitions. By definition $\nabla f = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \hat{e_i}$ where $x_i$ is the coordinate by which you are differentiating and $\hat{e_i}$ is the corresponding unit vector.
Given a vector $\vec{E}$ then $\nabla \cdot  \vec{E}= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial E_i}{\partial x_i}$ where $x_i$ is as before and $E_i$ is the i_th component of $\vec{E}$.
So $\nabla ^2 f= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}$
From here you should be able to setup a differential equation using separation. Unlike the 3d case, you'll end up with having to worry about 4 eigenvalues. If I'm not mistaken, solutions will be sums of the product of real and complex exponentials, i.e. Exponential decays, growths, and sinusoidal functions in each of the 4 coordinates.
This is also possible with non-cartesian coordinates.
You probably don't want to use this if one of your coordinates is time.
You can define the Laplacian in higher dimensions, but if you have more than 3 spatial dimensions and time doesn't behave a little differently, you are entering speculative physics and geometry.
